# Regex - allow some characters only if the string contains any other characters

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I've been messing around with regex for a few days now and I've done everything but one small thing.

```
^[-,.'\s\p{L}]{1,}$
```

For example, the regex above should allow any name (including whitespaces, commas, etc.), but right now it also counts " " and ",.-' " as names. The question is simple: how can I prevent that? Sorry if that's a duplicate question, I couldn't find an exact same problem.

Comment: Is it for JS and PHP? `\p{L}` is supported by PHP, but not JS.

Comment: For some reason it shows JS as the main category, this regex here is for PHP, but the question applies for both, the syntax is pretty much the same and I'm using both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to allow any number of your allowed characters before, **and** after, a *real* character.

I.e. `^[-,.'\s\p{L}]*\p{L}[-,.'\s\p{L}]*$`

Regards

Comment: Done, didn't notice the button before :D